# How to iteratively define functions using values from another array

Tags: python, function, loops, indexing, lambda

Suppose I have a list of coefficients: `coeff = [0, 1, 2]` and I wish to iteratively define 3 functions that depend on the coefficients to get: `phi = [lambda x: coeff[0]*(x-0), lambda x: coeff[1]*(x-1), lambda x: coeff[2]*(x-2)]`

The code I tried is:

```
for i in range(3):
    phi.append(lambda x, i=i: coeff[i] * (x - i))
```

but I get an error `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`.

I assume the problem is my reference to `coeff[i]` in the `lambda` function, but I don't fully understand the problem and not sure how to resolve. Thanks.

Edit:
I thought the above was a simplified example of my actual program:

```
l = 3
coeff = []
phi = []
hat = []
curve = lambda x: sin(x*pi)*x**2

nodes = linspace(0, 1, 2**l+1, endpoint = True)

for n in nodes:
    coeff.append(curve(n))

for i in range(len(nodes)):
    phi.append(lambda x, i=i: coeff[i] * max(1 - abs(2**l * x - i), 0))
```

Edit 2: I realised the problem is elsewhere when I call on the functions in phi! I think the problem is with `coeff[1]` in the `lambda` function - preventing converting to Python scalar. Is there a way I can use the *value* of `coeff[i]` in the `lambda` function, rather than having `coeff[i]`?

```
for p in phi:
    hat.append(ax.get_graph(p, x_range=[0, 1], color=MAROON_C))
```

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Edit 3: The problem was elsewhere - this thread can be closed. Thanks all for helping.

Comment: The code you provided looks correct - I was able to run it with `coeff=[0, 1, 2]` and `phi=[]` before executing the provided code. What are the contents of `coeff`? I have a sneaking suspicion that it doesn't contain numbers but rather arrays with multiple elements each.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the main body to provide my actual program. I thought the example I gave was a simplified version, but I guess not!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
coeff = [0, 1, 2]
phi   = []
for i, c in enumerate(coeff):
  f = lambda x:  coeff[i] * (x-i)
  phi.append(f)
```

You now have three functions in `phi`:

- `f0 = coeff[0] * (x-0)`
- `f1 = coeff[1] * (x-1)`
- `f2 = coeff[2] * (x-2)`

Is that what you were looking to accomplish?